# added a line to an existing shell script and

Tags: bash, shell, vim, ubuntu-14.04, nano

now I get a bizarre error ***as if*** I have changed/lost a closing argument such as `fi`, statement closure such as `,` or a hidden series of tabs.

This is the message I get in my err file:

```
./cron_run.sh: line 156: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./cron_run.sh: line 156: `                  else'
```

Again, I did not touch these lines. Not even close and what I added was another operation to dump a mongo collection to the backup directory. So I had:

```
...start of script
mongodump... # this was existing
mongodump... # this was the addition
...rest of script (about 70) lines unchanged
```

Key point:

- the above lines worked
- the code/server executed as expected
- the error/crash occurred at the end of the process after execution (so the whole thing actually worked!)

I looked at the code with syntax highlighting (vim, nano) and I cannot see anything wrong with it (at least not an obvious thing such as a bracket, fi or missing back tick)!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Am afraid, `one` is helpless without actually seeing the script!

Comment: My guess would be an accidental change somewhere else, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the script itself. Try [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) -- it's much more reliable than syntax highlighting.

Comment: I appreciate this but will need to mask the entire script...in the meantime I used http://www.shellcheck.net/ and found no errors (1-2 recommendations though :) )

Comment: Also used Ultra Edit (http://www.ultraedit.com/downloads/uex.html). Can't see anything wrong... :(

Comment: Well obviously there is something wrong!  One possibility (I've seen this several times) is that `cron` (or whatever is running the script) is not picking-up the version of the script you think it is.  That can happen when someone changes `PATH` variable, for example.  I suggest you place some unique display (like `echo testing....`) in the script to make sure you are actually running the one you think you are.

Comment: Thought: if the shell script was running but somehow it got edited while running could that cause it to break? for example: cron-->shell-->start--> do stuff->python-->shell edited-->python done-->shell-->break (instead of finish')

Comment: @goggelj Yes. Bash doesn't read more than it needs to. If you edited the file while running, you'd see things like this.

Comment: Looks like the issue was due to editing the file mid run.